# not work http request with authorize in ionic 2 on android device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have two types of rest api from server.
1. free rest api(without auth)
2. rest api with authorize

for one type http request works without any problem.
but for rest api with authorize works in browser but does not work in android device.

I use following code :

```
  let req:RequestOptions=new RequestOptions( {
        method: RequestMethod.Get,
        url: AppGlobal.OAUTH.USER_AUTHORIZATION_URI,
    } );

   req.headers = new Headers( {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.access_token
    } );

 return this.http.request( new Request( req ) )
        .map( res => {
            return res.json().message || res.json();
        } )
        .catch( this.handleError )
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?  You can usually debug a running device with chrome://inspect

Answer (score 0):

import  http from angular

> import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http'

in constructor

> constructor(
>       private jwtService: JwtService,private http: Http   ) { }

set headers

```
private setHeaders(): Headers {
    let headersConfig = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

    if (this.jwtService.getToken()) {
      headersConfig['Authorization'] = `${this.jwtService.getToken()}`;
    }
    return new Headers(headersConfig);
  }

 get(route): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(AppEnvironment.apiUrl + route, {
      headers: this.setHeaders()
    }).map( res => {
            return res.json().message || res.json();
        } )
        .catch( this.handleError )

 post(route): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(AppEnvironment.apiUrl + route, {
      headers: this.setHeaders()
    }).map( res => {
            return res.json().message || res.json();
        } )
        .catch( this.handleError )
```